# How to grep strings that contain a query string with any 2 characters in the beginning "xxTHISISMYSTRING" from a file?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a multi-lined file in the format:

> hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh**hhaaaa**hhhhhhhhhhhhhh
>   hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh**oaaaaa**hhhhhhhhhhhhhh
>   hhhhhhhhhhhh**hbaaaa**hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
>   hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh**fbaaaa**hhhhhhhhhhhh

I want to find all strings that contain the "aaaa" motif as well as the two letters preceding it.

How would I grep out the strings: **hhaaaa, oaaaaa, hbaaaa, fbaaaa**? With "**aaaa**" as my input.

Comment: something like `grep '[A-Za-z]\{2\}aaaa' file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match *any* character in a regex, use `.`:

```
$ grep -o ..aaaa file
hhaaaa
hoaaaa
hbaaaa
fbaaaa
```

The `-o` option tells grep to print only the matches, not the context for the matches.

To restrict the match to *alphabetic* characters, use the alphabetic class:

```
$ grep -Eo '[[:alpha:]]{2}aaaa' file
hhaaaa
hoaaaa
hbaaaa
fbaaaa
```

`[[:alpha:]]` matches any alphabetic character.  Unlike `A-Z`, this is unicode-safe.  The `{2}` indicates two such characters.  To avoid backslashes, we have added the `-E` flag to turn on extended regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -oh "..aaaa" file.txt
```

will do.

> -h, --no-filename
>       Suppress the prefixing of file names on output. This is the default
>       when there is only  one  file  (or only standard input) to search.
>   -o, --only-matching
>       Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
>       with each such part on a separate output line.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -o '..aaaa' file
```

should do it. Had the objective been to count the total matches, then do:

```
grep -o '..aaaa' file | wc -l
```

GREP manpage says :

> -o, --only-matching
>  Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of
>   a matching line, with each    such part on a separate output line.

WC manpage says :

> -l, --lines
>   print the newline counts